# Stratum/Python "Method Not Found for Service"

Tags: python, service, methods, mining

We are trying to set-up a litecoin mining server with Stratum protocol for minelitecoin.com...

I am able to set-up the server and mining proxy, they are configured and running but when trying to connect miners to the server (even when using the stratum mining-proxy) we are receiving:

```
"Method 'subscribe' not found for service 'mining'."
```

We have followed all cloning/installation instructions provided by the README inside the package and have spent hours searching the net and digging through thousands of lines of Python to try and figure out what is happening.

The error is occurring in this function in protocol.py:

```
def dataReceived(self, data, request_counter=RequestCounter()):         

lines  = (self._buffer+data).split(self.delimiter)
    self._buffer = lines.pop(-1)
    request_counter.set_count(len(lines))

    for line in lines:
        if self.transport.disconnecting:
            return
        if len(line) > self.MAX_LENGTH:
            return self.lineLengthExceeded(line)
        else:
            self.lineReceived(line, request_counter)
    if len(self._buffer) > self.MAX_LENGTH:
        return self.lineLengthExceeded(self._buffer)
        if self.transport.disconnecting:
            return
        if len(line) > self.MAX_LENGTH:
            return self.lineLengthExceeded(line)
        else:
            self.lineReceived(line, request_counter)
    if len(self._buffer) > self.MAX_LENGTH:
        return self.lineLengthExceeded(self._buffer)
```

Specifically at this line:

```
        else:
            self.lineReceived(line, request_counter)
```

A full DEBUG output for the proxy service is available here:

```
http://pastebin.com/iTD5LCXD
```

Live output from the server side is here:

```
http://pastebin.com/3QKRAkbL
```

And logged output from the server (which seems much less descriptive) is here:

```
http://pastebin.com/H7k444RQ
```

We have been banging our heads against a wall for a couple days now, if anyone could help with this, it would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: When debugging really hard issued, cloning your app into a "fresh box" it's a must, so you can now if where the machine or the code the one who like to kidd you.